# Keyboard layout in LUKS prompt unusable (layout: russian, password: english)

Tags: keyboard-layout, luks, recovery-mode

i recently added the russian keyboard layout to gnome.
After a reboot, I am now unable to enter my password into the LUKS prompt because somehow the keyboard layout during boot was also changed.

Since the russian keyboard layout does not include many characters from the normal english keyboard layout, I can not boot.

BTW:
Ubuntu 18.04, I think (maybe .10 not 100% sure)
grub is still english

What can I do?

What I tried:

- Boot into a recovery console *before* the layout is set:

  - added init=/bin/sh to the linux ... commandline -> still asked for luks password and had russian keyboard layout
  - someone mentioned putting a 1 to the end of that same line could help (runlevel 1 or something) -> same
- Try entering my password using Alt+number

  - seems not to work, when I'm in a recovery console it just puts the number as if i didn't press alt (since its a laptop, only tried the numbers above the letters, not numpad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed:

How to temporary get into system again:

- boot with rdinit=/bin/sh
- remove /etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz
- exec /init

this boots normally, does not change the keymap to russian(or whichever keymap your problem waas), stays default english

how to fix permanently:

- change the order of keymaps in gnome so your preferred during boot is first
- sudo update-initramfs -u

for me, the most important and missing piece was rdinit=/bin/sh